# Select & replace with relative positions

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I'd like to select all the "diff." and replace them by the closest number upper them. Ie: here the suff. row 2 = 1, the suff. row 4&5 = 2. I tried with =replace and relative positions but I could not manage successfully. I'm not against VBA if it's the best way.

Thanks.

[image: example]

Comment: Note that there's no `diff.` in your screenshot, maybe you meant `suff.` in the question body? That said, I think you need VBA here.

Comment: Loop through each cell in `Range("A1"A16")` and use an `IF` statement to test each cell, and if "stuff." then make the cell value equal to the cell above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in cell `B1` and then drag down.

```
=IF(A1="suff.", MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(A1),1))),A1)
```

You can then copy and paste the results into column A.

Comment: wow thanks I would never have been able to find that. Even now I barely understand how the formula is working. Do you mind giving an explanation ? Esp. from "indirect(...)"

Comment: The `INDIRECT( ... )` is building the range reference for the `MAX()` function. `Address(1,1)` refers to cell `A1` and does not change. `Address(ROW(A1),1)` uses `ROW()` to update the row reference. Example: when the formula is in cell `B3` then the range for the `MAX()` function is effectively `A1:A3`.

Comment: The ADDRESS and INDIRECT are overkill: `=IF(A1="suff.",MAX($A$1:A1),A1)`.

Comment: Good shout @BigBen. That's much simpler. Thanks.